# login API flutter is not working properly

Tags: flutter, api

this is my API connecting code for login page in my app. but I'm getting "something went wrong" snack bar with a Http status error [400]. how should I correct this? below image showing my postman request. it works successfully. error is on the below code. but I'm struggling to find. appriciate your help on this.

[image]

```
class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController walletEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController usernameEditingController = new TextEditingController();


  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String username = "";
  String wallet_address = "";
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool typing = true;
  bool _isObscure = true;

  // bool newValue = true;
  bool checkedValue = true;

 

    Future LoginData() async {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
          typing = false;
        });
        try {
          var response = await Dio().post(BASE_API + 'user/login',
              data: {"username": username, "password": password, wallet_address:"wallet_address"});
    
          if (response.data["status"] == "LoginSuccess") {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
    
            Get.snackbar(
              "success",
              "logged in successfully",
              backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
              colorText: textWhite,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: Colors.grey,
            );
    
            Get.to(BottomNavigation());
          } else {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
              typing = true;
            });
            Get.snackbar(
              "error",
              "No User Found",
              backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
              colorText: textWhite,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: Colors.grey,
            );
          }
          print("res: $response");
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
            typing = true;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
            typing = true;
          });
          Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong.Please contact admin",
              backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: Colors.grey,
              colorText: Colors.white,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline_outlined,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 30,
              ));
          print(e);
        }
      }
```

Comment: from where your user name and password come from, Can you share your code?

Comment: Hard write the post data value and try again! >> 
data: {"username": "Nirasha", "password": "123456", wallet_address:"0x"}

Comment: I have re edit the question with code. please refer

Comment: Maybe the typo, wallet_address in the body, {"username": username, "password": password, wallet_address:"wallet_address"}, will not work like in Postman.

Comment: where should I change?

Comment: the problem is solved. thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
final data = {
'username': emailEditingController.text,
'password': passwordEditingController.text,
'wallet_address': '0x',
};
```

check your data field and print it in the console and make sure that the data are correct.
then check your URL and print it in the console

```
 ///try to print your data here
    var response = await Dio().post('${BASE_API}user/login',
              data: data);
              ///print your response here
              print(response.data.toString());
          if (response.data["status"] == "LoginSuccess") {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
    
            Get.snackbar(
              "success",
              "logged in successfully",
              backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
              colorText: textWhite,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: Colors.grey,
            );
    
            Get.to(BottomNavigation());
```